# How to use list variables defined using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have defined a variable in my defaults as a list:

```
aws-sec-group-name:
    - "es-external"
    - "elasticsearch-production"
```

I am trying to use the above variable in my task playbook as follows:

```
---
  - name: Create EC2 instances
    ec2:
      keyname: "{{ aws-key-name }}"
      #group: "{{ aws-sec-group-name }}"
      instance_type: "{{ aws-instance-type }}"
      image: "{{ aws-ami }}"
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 500
      count: 2
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ aws-tag-name }}"
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet-id }}"
      group: ["{{ aws-sec-group-name.[0] }}","{{ aws-sec-group-name.[1] }}"].
```

Which is not the right way.

Can someone tell me how to use list variable?

And also since the count is 2, I am also interested in knowing if i can add -1- and -2- in the Name tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how to use list variable?

Here you are:

1. Fix the name of the variable as they cannot contain dashes:

   ```
   aws_sec_group_name:
     - "es-external"
     - "elasticsearch-production"
   ```
2. Use the variable:

   ```
   group: "{{ aws_sec_group_name }}"
   ```